# w3wp.exe consuming large amount of RAM

Tags: .net-4.0, iis-6

I noticed the other day that it seems like all the w3wp.exe running on my server are consuming way more RAM than I would expect. So I created test web application with a single aspx page and then a vanilla global.asax page as well (default methods, no additional code). I then deployed that site to IIS6 with a target framework of 4.0 built in release mode with debug set to "false". The site is also set up under it's own application pool. I then used issapp.vbs to figure out which w3wp.exe this test site was running under. I was surprised to see that the single site with 1 page was using almost 40mb of ram.

40mb of RAM seems like a lot for a single page website. Is this normal and if so why? Is there anything I can do to reduce the memory footprint?

I also noticed that each time the default page was refreshed that the w3wp.exe grew a little bit more. Is IIS6 caching the same page over and over?

Comment: May I suggest upgrading from IIS 6? It's almost as horrid as IE 6. Is it possible anytime soon?

Comment: Yeah, actually that is a possibility in the very near future. Are you suggesting then that the same site would run with a smaller memory footprint in IIS7?

Comment: Probably yes. I believe it will be smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

40Mb for a single AppDomain (irrespective of how many pages you have) is alright. Consider that .NET is a managed environment and the app pool contains a large majority of the logic and heap for serving requests. In many cases it also will be less eager to free up RAM, if the RAM is not under contention (demanded by other parts of the system).
You can share app pools amongst different websites, and the "overhead" of the sandbox becomes less proportionate to your perception of what is acceptable. However, I don't think this is bad at all.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to optimize the case where you have no load and no clients. That really isn't sensible. Optimize for a realistic use case.

You don't build a factory and then try to get it to make one item as efficiently as possible. You try to get it to crank them out efficiently by the dozens.

Comment: While you are correct, it does sound like a real problem and with a proper stress test I believe the memory usage will grow exponentially.

Comment: I agree with what your saying but you've really avoid the question entirely, in my opinion at least. It seems a bit absurd that a site with almost literally no code which literally does nothing would consume so much RAM.

Comment: It does seem kind of absurd that you need a giant factory with 100 workers to make one car -- because you don't. But A system optimized for making one car looks nothing like a system optimized for making hundreds. You have the latter and should not be surprised that it looks nothing like the former.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that's a great analogy

Comment: @AlexNorcliffe Perhaps, but I feel that from a technical standpoint it fails to answer any part of the question.

Comment: It answers the entire question. The crux of the question was: "Is this normal and if so why?" Which it answers. Yes, it's normal. It's because the software isn't designed for this casel. "Is there anything I can do to reduce the memory footprint?" You can switch to a program optimized for lower load or smaller applications, but you probably don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an issue, since it is quite normal. Your .NET Framework is getting loaded and hence the size. When a real issue happens, you would have to use certain post production or profiling tools to get it fixed. Sharing some articles for memory and post production debugging just in case you need it in future.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188781.aspx
http://aspalliance.com/1350_Post_Production_Debugging_for_ASPNET_Applications__Part_1.all
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/09/06/net-memory-usage-a-restaurant-analogy.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/09/12/asp-net-memory-issues-high-memory-usage-with-ajaxpro.aspx